# Pandas, how to seperate dataframe string if symbol detect?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below:

Table A:

```
No     Course      Name          
1      BM          GAR\samege    
2      BI          GER\yun       
3      MM          steli                      
4      SC          ilo18yu
```

I wish to split the string at **Name** column when detecting the symbol(blackslash). Anyone have ideas on this?
Below is my expected output
Output:

```
No     Course      Name           Domain       id
1      BM          GAR\samege     GAR          samege
2      BI          GER\yun        GER          yun
3      MM          steli                       steli
4      SC          ilo18yu                     ilo18yu
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with set new columns by [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) by length of splitted values:

```
s = df['Name'].str.split('\\')
df['domain'] = np.where(s.str.len().eq(1), '', s.str[0])
df['id'] = s.str[-1]
print (df)
   No Course        Name domain       id
0   1     BM  GAR\samege    GAR   samege
1   2     BI     GER\yun    GER      yun
2   3     MM       steli           steli
3   4     SC     ilo18yu         ilo18yu
```

Another idea:

```
s = df['Name'].str.split('\\').str[::-1]

df[['domain', 'id']] = pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), index=df.index).iloc[:, ::-1]
print (df)
   No Course        Name domain       id
0   1     BM  GAR\samege    GAR   samege
1   2     BI     GER\yun    GER      yun
2   3     MM       steli   None    steli
3   4     SC     ilo18yu   None  ilo18yu
```

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
df[['domain', 'id']]= df['Name'].str.split('\\', expand=True)
```

---

```
    No  Course  Name    domain  id
0   1   BM  GAR\samege  GAR     samege
1   2   BI  GER\yun     GER     yun
2   3   MM  steli       steli   None
3   4   SC  ilo18yu     ilo18yu None
```

## Edit:

Try:

```
df[['domain', 'id']] = pd.DataFrame([x.split('\\') if len(x.split('\\'))==(2) else ['None', x] for x in df['Name']])
```

---

```
    No  Course  Name        domain  id
0   1   BM      GAR\samege  GAR     samege
1   2   BI      GER\yun     GER     yun
2   3   MM      steli       None    steli
3   4   SC      ilo18yu     None    ilo18yu
```

Comment: Hi, I actually facing trouble on those name without the symbol, for those name without symbol, the name should put under id, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Check the updated answer

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure there'd be a shorter approach to this problem, but you may try this:

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame()
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Name'].find('\\') != -1:
        splitstr = row['Name'].split('\\')
        domain = splitstr[0]
        id = splitstr[1]
    else:
        domain = np.nan
        id = row['Name']
    
    final = pd.DataFrame([[row['Course'],row['Name'],domain,id]],columns=['Course','Name','Domain','Id'])
    newdf = newdf.append(final)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.split`, and split on `'\\'`:

```
df[['Domain','id']] = df['Name'].str.split('\\',expand=True)
```

which prints your desired output:

```
   No Course        Name   Domain      id
0   1     BM  GAR\samege      GAR  samege
1   2     BI     GER\yun      GER     yun
2   3     MM       steli    steli    None
3   4     SC     ilo18yu  ilo18yu    None
```

**If you want to put the name under ID, when ID is 'None'**:

```
import numpy as np
df['id'] = np.where(df['id'].isnull(),df['Name'],df['id'])
```

which prints:

```
   No Course        Name   Domain       id
0   1     BM  GAR\samege      GAR   samege
1   2     BI     GER\yun      GER      yun
2   3     MM       steli    steli    steli
3   4     SC     ilo18yu  ilo18yu  ilo18yu
```